# Power / sample size estimation for chi-square test with continuity correction in R

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, sample-size, statistical-power

1._Some authors mention that they estimate sample size for chi-square test *with continuity correction*. For instance:

> Sample-size calculation is based on Pearson's Chi-square test with a two-sided alpha error of 0.05 and 90% power. We calculated that we would need a sample size of 5300 participants per group using the continuity correction resulting in the total study population of 10,600
> patients.

http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cct.2017.05.011

Are there special formulas for power estimation for chi-square test with continuity correction? If so, are there packages in R which implement such formulas?

The common pwr.chisq.test() function has no arguments concerning continuity correction.

2._Consider the following example. I expect 10% of (adverse) events in group A and 5% of events in group B. I wish to calculate the power for chi-square test with continuity correction for 500 subjects in group A and 500 subjects in group B. In order to do it, I use the following code

```
runs=100000 # simulation runs

n=1000 #sample size
m=n/2 #size of each group

rnda=rbinom(runs, m, .10) #draw number of events in group A
rndb=rbinom(runs, m, .05) #draw number of events in group B

pvals=numeric(runs)
for (j in 1:runs) {
  a=matrix(c(rnda[j],m-rnda[j],rndb[j],m-rndb[j]),nrow=2)
  pvals[j]=chisq.test(a, correct=T)$p.value
}

mean(pvals < 0.05)
```

The code yields power 83%. However, the code does not account for the cases when there are less events in group A than in group B.

The question is: if I calculate sample size for a superiority trial, then must I account for such cases, and so replace the last line with

```
mean(pvals < 0.05 & rnda >= rndb)
```

? In this case I get the same 83% power, but theoretically must it be done?

Comment: In general, simulating data is one way to do power calculations. Fake data with your effect size, run your test, record the p value, repeat 100 times, calculate your power.

Comment: Continuity correction with ten thousand observations is unlikely to make any difference.  Use the standard chi-squared and non-central chi-squared formulas to estimate power with great accuracy.  Both of these distribution functions are available in base `R`: see the help page for `Chisquare`.

Comment: @whuber There will be about 1000 observations. For such sizes, continuity correction is important.

Comment: @dash2 Thank you very much for your advice. Finally I ended up doing the simulations. For my probabilities, 100,000 or more simulation runs were needed.

Comment: @Viktor it depends on the number of observations in the smallest category. For instance with 2% mortality you get 106 cases and the correction is not having much effect or worse it will overcorrect.